# Executing JAR file within another java application

Tags: java, jar, cmd, external

I'm trying to run a External Jar file, without actually inserting it into my jar itself. Because the jar file needs to be located in the same folder as the main jar file.

So, Within the main jar file I want to execute the other executable jar file, And I need to be able to know when the jar file is ended AND when you close the main jar file, the jar file that is started within the jar file needs to be closed to,

I currently do that by using this code:

```
public void LaunchLatestBuild()
  {
    try {
      String path = new File(".").getCanonicalPath() + 
        "\\externaljar.jar";
      List commands = new ArrayList();
      commands.add(getJreExecutable().toString());
      commands.add("-Xmx" + this.btd_serverram + "M");
      commands.add("-Xms" + this.btd_serverram + "M");
      commands.add("-jar");
      commands.add(path);

      int returnint = launch(commands); //It just waits and stops the tread here. And my Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook doesn't get triggerd.

      if (returnint != 201) //201 is a custom exit code I 'use' to know when the app needs a restart or not.
      {
        System.out.println("No restart needed! Closing...");
        System.exit(1);
      }
      else
      {
        CloseCraftBukkit();

        Launcher.main(new String[] { "" });
      }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println(e.toString());
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  public int launch(List<String> cmdarray) throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(cmdarray);
    processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
    this.CBProcess = processBuilder.start();
    InputStream in = this.CBProcess.getInputStream();
    while (true) {
      int r = in.read(buffer);
      if (r <= 0) {
        break;
      }
      System.out.write(buffer, 0, r);
    }

    return this.CBProcess.exitValue();
  }
```

Limitations of this code:

- Doesn't close my externaljar.jar java
  process on exit of the main
  application.
- Cannot redirect input if main console, to external jar.

That are the most Important things I need.

I hope someone can tell me how I should do this.

Current source code is available at:
http://code.google.com/p/bukkit-to-date/

Comment: Can you post the code for `launch`

Comment: @spintheblack: Added in main post

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just set your classpath so that it includes the second jar, and then you can simply use it as a library ? You can even invoke the `MainClass.main()` method manually, if you really want that to be executed, but from within the same VM and without spawning a separate process.

EDIT: If you don't know the name of the jar file when your application is launched, but you'll only figure that out at runtime, in order to invoke it, create a [URLClassLoader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) provided with the path to your jar file and then:

```
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(
        new File("/path/to/your/jar/file.jar").toURI().toURL() );

ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
// switch to your custom CL
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(urlClassLoader);
// do your stuff with the other jar
// ....................
// now switch back to the original CL
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);
```

Or simply grab a reference to a class in that other jar and make use of reflection:

```
Class<?> c = urlClassLoader.loadClass("org.ogher.packag.ClassFromExternalJar");
```

Comment: I want that, But the point is that the file constantly changes. Is that a problem when using classpath?

Because I thought it imports the whole jar file right? And that file can also not be there.

Comment: In this case, one solution would be to have a custom classloader as a child of the system one and then you can load whatever you want when you need it.

Comment: Can anyone explain how to do that? 
I also need to be able to detect that the external jar stopped itself.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the external jar stopped itself" ? (I tried to explain with an edit, by the way).

Comment: When the external jar tries to terminate the process. I need to know that.

Comment: But since you're invoking methods on objects, you will either invoke them synchronously or you can join() the other thread to wait for it, so this is not a problem at all.

Comment: I edited the answer again to make it a little more explicit... To rephrase the above,now there's no "jar" that needs to terminate, just Java method invocations which you can perform synchronously or `join()`.

Comment: @WMisiedjan you would have to set a custom SecurityManager with System.setSecurityManager() to catch these requests and turn them into exceptions. http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html._____________ _______________ For the classloader you can use the java.net.URLClassloader to load its main class (findClass()) and execute its main method with reflection.http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#findClass%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: GREAT! How do I now execute for example: 'code' c.getMethod("main", c)

Comment: I already have loaded the class: "org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main" I now only need to execute the method main.

Comment: try `Method mainMethod = yourClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);` and then `mainMethod.invoke(new String[0])`.

Comment: Yeah, Thank you all! How do I now get the exit code of that method?

Comment: @Costi Ciudatu:
You mean exit codes? Because I need a way to let the external jar know the main jar that it needs a restart So the main jar loads the external jar again.

Comment: The `main` method returns void, so there's no "exit code" involved, since there's no `exit`.

Comment: @Costi Ciudatu: I need a way to let the main jar know that the external jar needs a restart, So the main jar loads the external jar again.

Comment: @WMisiedjan the SecurityManager I mentioned before should throw an exception when you call System.exit(), subclass the exception to add the exit code, you can read the code when you catch it.

Comment: I now acctually Have Everything I need, Can get the exit code, etc. But how do I UNLOAD the jar file from the virtual machine? So it isn't in use anymore. Because the same app needs to replace the external jar file with an update on a specific exit code. I already tried some things but without succes.

Comment: Simply instantiate a new URLClassLoader with the new jar and let the old CL be collected by the GC (don't keep references to that class loader or the class that you loaded with it).

Comment: Whats GC?
And if you want you can check out what I currently have on:
http://code.google.com/p/bukkit-to-date/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FBukkitToDateLauncher%2Fsrc%2Fcom%2Fbukkittodate%2FWMisiedjan%2FBukkitToDateLauncher

Comment: GC = Garbage Collector, I'll try to check your code and get back to you.

Comment: Hmm.. first thing I noticed, you're using the `setContextClassLoader()` although you invoke the main method via reflection. When using reflection, there's no need to change the thread class loader. Now I still don't really see what your problem is. What do you mean "unload from the VM" ? If you want to load another jar, simply instantiate yet another URLClassLoader with the new URL and you'll get the new version. The old reference gets lost "by itself", via garbage collection. Just make sure you don't keep the class loader or the class that you load as class/instance variable.

Comment: The problem is that I don't need an other. I need the SAME one to be deleted/replaced afterwards. I Updated my code to the things you said. I cleaned all the vars and then let GC run.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's the same path or a different one. Just have a brand new URLClassLoader instantiated with the same File URL and this should be it.

Comment: Yes, But I need to replace it before I reloaded it. In the source code on:
https://code.google.com/p/bukkit-to-date/

I try to delete the 'craftbukkit.jar'. So I can afterwards copy the new version there and THEN load it again.

Comment: Now I get it: you want to delete the file currently loaded with the `URLClassLoader` and Windows won't let you. Is this right ?

Comment: The `.close()` method (that does exactly that: frees resources used by the CL) is only available for `URLClassLoader` in Java 7, afaik. As a workaround, I just found out of an alternative: `org.apache.xbean.classloader.JarFileClassLoader`, that is able to close connections to jar files. Maybe that could help you.

Comment: Somehow Eclipse doesn't know about org.apache.xbean.classloader.JarFileClassLoader I probably need to download some files?

Nevermind, Already found. Tnx!

Comment: YES THANK YOU! IT COMPLETELY WORKS NOW! REALLY APPRECIATE IT!

Comment: I got a problem now, When trying to detect a restart, It detects it but as soon as I execute the Main() function from the Main class again, it shuts itself down.

Anyone know what causes this? And how can I prevent it?