# How to cancel a System.Exit and Restart the application in Java

Tags: java, restart

For an Application I need to restart the application's Main class/function in itself.

So, What is the best way to detect a Application Exit on a Specific code, And then restart itself?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) method.

**But beware:** since you're saying that you want to restart the main method on System.exit, you may be introducing a possibility to get into an infinite loop.

Comment: Thats why I need the exit code... How Do I get the exit code?

Comment: I don't think this works.  A shutdown hook cannot stop the JVM from shutting down, or (by itself) cause the JVM from restarting.

Comment: Even if it did stop, I wouldn't advocate using one because that's not what shutdown hooks are meant for. They are to finish off some clean-up operations before the JVM exits. Not to prevent it from exiting in the first place.

Comment: I tried some other things but without success.  Hope that some can give me a small example?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to implement the restart logic in a launcher or a wrapper script.

I'm pretty sure it is not possible to implement full JVM restart in pure Java in the application's own JVM.  And nothing short of a full JVM restart is required to do things like:

- change the JVM options (e.g. heap size),
- clear out leaked objects, or
- get rid of Java threads that don't respond to `Thread.interrupt()`.

Comment: You should modify your launcher to check the JVM process' exit code and restart if required.

Comment: I tried some other things but without success.  Hope that some can give me a small example?

Answer (score 0):

Why not embedding your so called main method in a Launcher main method ?

Your launcher class uses a SecurityManager that forbids calls to System.exit. This way, when initial maint ries to exit, a SecurityException is throwed (and catched in Launcher). The Launcher then restarts the initial main.

Comment: I already have like a Launcher, And I invoke a other JAR.

Seen here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4971791/executing-jar-file-within-a-other-java-application

It works. I can even unload the invoked jar now, But I sOMEhow, cannot prevent it from closing the VM.

And If it trows a SecurityException, it trows it not in the Launcher but in the Invoked JAR right?

Edit: It somehow closes when I try to restart the Main function again I think.

Comment: Can anyone show me a small example?

I already tried some things with the SecurityException.

You can see the source if you want on:
http://code.google.com/p/bukkit-to-date/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FBukkitToDateLauncher%2Fsrc%2Fnet%2FWMisiedjan%2FBukkitToDate%2FLauncher

Answer (score -1):

`finally` acts like a destructor, therefore we can restart an application like this. Warning : `finally` is a bad replacement to finalize, and also it is not a proper destructor.

```
public class RestartDemo
{
    public void oddeven(int x)
    {
        if(x % 2 != 0)
        {
            try
            {
                this.restart();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            { 
                 //do nothing
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(x + " is even");
        }
    }

    public void restart()throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("Force restart!");
        }
        finally
        {
            RestartDemo.main(new String[0]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        RestartDemo r = new RestartDemo();
        r.oddeven((int)(Math.random() * 100));
    }
}
```